# Documents downloaded as a ZIP file - any way of stopping this?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I need to think of a way to stop multiple documents to be downloaded as a ZIP on SharePoint Online.

Can anyone think of a way for this not to happen? I do realise it is default action.

Answer (score 1):

It’s by design that we can only get the zip file when download multiple documents at a time.

As a workaround, we can return to classic experience and click “Open with explorer” to copy and paste documents in windows explorer.

Or sync the document library using OneDrive and copy/paste the documents.